# In Spark, is it faster to join all your dataframes and pick from those, build up by joining intermediary DFs?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm on Spark 1.6 right now, and I'm wondering:

Say I have data that links departments to business units to managers to salespeople to customers. It's one table for each of these stored in parquet and read into a dataframe.

Lets say I need a few things within this relationship, like

- customers by manager, customers by department and salespeople by department

Lets also say that customers can be associated with multiple business units within a department,

e.g. linking them all and grouping by department would result in multiple of the same customer associated with each department, potentially. So, this will also involve dropping duplicates.

**I have a few questions:**

> - Is spark optimized to where it's faster not to do intermediary dataframes, e.g. it would be faster to do department.join(bus
>     unit,...).join(manager...).join(salesman...).join(customer...).groupby(departmentID,customerID)
>     and do the same for department->manager->salesman, vs doing one big
>     one, vs doing dept->bus unit->manager->salesman to get salesman by
>     dept and then joining customer to that to get customer by dept?
> - Is it faster to just join all of these into one dataframe and then do all my operations on that, or make smaller ad-hoc ones, e.g. would
>     I want to do department->business unit->manager->salesperson->customer
>     and then groupby department and get customers, groupby department and
>     get salespeople, etc. or would I just want to make a dataframe
>     department->business unit->manager->salesperson to get salesperson by
>     department, then join that to customers to get customers by
>     department, etc.?
> - Is it faster if I did do a big, completely combined dataframe to just select from it the columns I need and then do it, e.g. dep->bus
>     unit->manager->salesperson->customer.select(department ID, department
>     name,customerID,customerName).groupby(department
>     ID).removeduplicates(department ID, customerID)    or to just do the
>     groupby and remove duplicates on the main dataframe and then select
>     what I want out of it?

Comment: It is more about getting the correct answers. I would recommend you approach it like with SQL. Moreover the volume of data shouls be manageable from this scenario. Its not like you are processing telecom records.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your input. I'll worry about accuracy and then see what I can do for tweaking.